# javascript adding a variable to make an image url

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I can add a variable to javascript function so that I can better place my url. Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    var img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#loader').removeClass('loading').append(this);
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }).error(function () {
    }).attr('src', 'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2405/2238919394_4c9b5aa921_o.jpg');
});
```

Basically that is the working code. I wanted to add a variable as a change. Here is the code:

```
}).attr('src', x);
    x = 'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2405/2238919394_4c9b5aa921_o.jpg';
    });
```

How can I add my variable?

Comment: How about declaring the variable before you use it ?

Comment: Do you really need the variable..?

Comment: mmmmmm true.... how can I put 2 variables next to each other?  x.x?

Comment: x + x   okkkk I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(function () {
     var img = new Image();
     var x = 'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2405/2238919394_4c9b5aa921_o.jpg';
     $(img).load(function () {
         $(this).hide();
         $('#loader').removeClass('loading').append(this);
         $(this).fadeIn();
     }).error(function () {
     }).attr('src', x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable before you use it.

```
$(function () {
var img = new Image();

var x = 'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2405/2238919394_4c9b5aa921_o.jpg';

$(img).load(function () {
$(this).hide();
$('#loader').removeClass('loading').append(this);
$(this).fadeIn();
}).error(function () {
}).attr('src', x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the src after you've created the variable but before you assign the load handler.

```
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'url.jpg';
    $(img).load(...);
```